# Copying ranges in excel but keeping cell sizes

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, cell

I have a simple add in that copies a range and pastes it somewhere else. Everything works like intended, except that the cell sizes get reset to default...

This is a snippet responsible for this operation :

```
var excel = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Excel.Application;

int index = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index;

Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = excel.Worksheets[index] as Excel.Worksheet;
Excel.Worksheet newSheet = excel.Worksheets.Add();

Excel.Range toCopy = activeSheet.UsedRange;
toCopy.Copy();
Excel.Range range = newSheet.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Range;
range.Select();
newSheet.Paste();
```

Now how could I keep the cell sizes while copying and pasting them?

Comment: Did you try [PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial.aspx) on that `range` instance with `xlPasteAll` as the first argument?

Comment: By changing the line newSheet.Paste(); to newSheet.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlpasteType.xlPasteAll); I now run into System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC' exception. I haven't used pasteSpecial before, I might be missing something here.

Comment: the PasteSpecial on the Worksheet type is different from the the one on Range. That is why I explicitly said to call it on `range` like so `range.PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll, /* add other arguments if needed */)`

Comment: Alright, that doesn't throw any errors. But sadly the cells still get resized.

Comment: I just did that with two special pastes instead.

Comment: It's the same when using Excel as an end user. In order to also paste the column widths to the destination, you have to perform to paste oerations:

1. Do a normal "Paste" as you do in your code
2. Do a PasteSpecial(Excel.XlpasteType.xlPasteColumnWidths)

This copies the column width of the source to the destination. However, I don't know any method for also copying the cell heights, if this is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason xlPasteAll doesn't work on cell width, so I replaced the line

```
newSheet.Paste();
```

with those two

```
range.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteColumnWidths);
range.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll);
```

and now it works.